# LESS conditional variable change inside mixin

Tags: variables, less, conditional-statements, less-mixins

I need to achieve such effect, but even when @padding actually < @height it still use multiplier value 2, which is non-sense...Is there any limitation i don't know about?

```
.btn-svg-offset(@height, @padding) {
    @paddings-n: floor(@height / @padding);
    @multiplier: 2;

    & when (@padding < @height) {
        @multiplier: 1;
    }

    @btn-svg-offset: @padding + ((@height / @multiplier) * @paddings-n);
};
```

Any workarounds are welcome)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`& when` is not `if` (they usually say so just for short). `& {...}` is still a regular ruleset with its own scope, and variables defined inside a ruleset are not visible in outer scopes.

To achieve what you need, rewrite this using conditional mixins (mixin's internals (incl. variables) are actually expanded into the caller scope):

```css
.btn-svg-offset(@height, @padding) {
    @paddings-n: floor(@height / @padding);

    .-() {@multiplier: 2} .-;
    .-() when (@padding < @height) {
        @multiplier: 1;
    }

    @btn-svg-offset: @padding + ((@height / @multiplier) * @paddings-n);
}
```

Note that you can put the same condition onto the `.btn-svg-offset` mixin itself (so in real code it does not have to be that verbose as in my example... Exact code may vary though depending on the mixin usage and its other internals).

(Upd.) For example the following code (certain variations are possible too) would be an equivalent:

```css
.btn-svg-offset(@height, @padding, @multiplier: 2) {
    @paddings-n: floor(@height / @padding);
    @btn-svg-offset: @padding + @height / @multiplier * @paddings-n;
}

.btn-svg-offset(@height, @padding) when (@padding < @height) {
    .btn-svg-offset(@height, @padding, 1);
}
```

Comment: Hey man, thx very nice this .- ! Problem is, part with .- when (@padding < @height) { still doesn't work :( Any ideas why? First declaration works though)

Comment: P.S. LESS should have real if by now, would be extremely handy)) I know that SASS have,  but i hate it)

Comment: i think both solutions won't work cause `@multiplier: 2` leak to the caller scope before the `when` has been called and then "Variable defined directly in callers scope can not be overriden." (when using mixins as functions). So you will need two `btn-svg-offset` mixins with different quards to solve this. I'm not sure this is some kind of a bug. @seven-phases-max says: `& {...} is still a regular ruleset`. But i expect that `.mixin { & when (){}}` should act like `.mixin{}` followed by  `.mixin when(){}`

Comment: @failure13 Sorry, my mistake... Fixed now. I mistakenly removed required parens when reformatting the code.  (just in case here's [demo test](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/YPbOBR?editors=010) - click on `eye` icon to see the compiled CSS result).

Comment: @seven-phases-max It works now, awesome! Thx a lot) Wish i could already vote up)

Comment: @BassJobsen, "cause `@multiplier: 2` leak to the caller scope before the when has been called" - Not really, both definitions of the same mixin are expanded simultaneously (they would not if they were different mixins). For more details see [#80](https://github.com/less/less-docs/issues/80#issuecomment-32119684).

Comment: ... (continuing prev. comment) - "But i expect that `.mixin { & when (){}}` should act like `.mixin{} followed by .mixin when(){}`" not quite too. Confusing point is probably the fact that CSS properties of the `& {}` block are merged to the parent ruleset in the end (to remove duplicated selectors), but this does not mean that it should affect variable and mixins visibility in any way (there're debates about that at #1877 and #2072, and most likely the proposed changes won't pass... Mary and me are against it - as it will break just too many scoping rules...).

Comment: @seven-phases-max thank for your explanation. I see (and understand) your mixin solution work now. I also add a comment to https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2072. I think that having the same result (scope) for the nested `& when` in mixins won't have to break the "block are merged to the parent ruleset in the end". (merging at the end, means evaluating mixins top bottom?)