# Less: set variable in when statement

Tags: if-statement, less

I need to set a variable depending on another variable passed to a mixin.

F.e.

```
#make-grid(@columns){
 when(@columns = 10){
  @a: 1;
 }
}
```

This is giving me a compile error "unrecognised input"

Comment: There's no such statement as `when {...}`. `When` is either a [mixin](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-mixin-guards-feature) or a [ruleset](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-mixin-guards-feature) guard. Probably you mean `& when {...}` but that way the variable you define won't be visible outside of the closest brackets. In short see the duplicates of your Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29496933,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25287904,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23738798 etc.

Comment: See also [`if` function](http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-if) in Less 3.x.